# Android: Where clause with two parameters in the shame row

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, where-clause

I want take data from a row with two parameters, and only return the first.

This is my code:

```
String[] projection = { VehiculoContentProv.Consumos.ID_VEH_C, 
                        VehiculoContentProv.Consumos.ID_CALCULO_KL,
                        VehiculoContentProv.Consumos.ID_CALCULO_MG};

String selection =  "_idv =" + idV1 + " AND " + idV2;

 cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(this, VehiculoContentProv.CONTENT_URI_CONSUMO, 
                                         projection, 
                                         selection, null, null);
```

thanks a lot

Comment: Could you explain in plain words which results are you expecting?

Comment: you wana `column1=param1 AND column2=param2` or `column1=param1 OR column1=param2` which can be also written as `column1 IN (param1,param2)` .... your `selection` has no sens: `column1=param1 AND param2` and for your sanity use selection and selectionArgs like: `column1=? OR column1=?` then `new String[] {parma1, param2}`(instead next(after selection) null in CursorLoader constructor)

Comment: Thanks for the response, its dificult for me express myself in english. I am spanish. I try to explain better:    I wana the data of the columns ID_CALCULO_KL and ID_CALCULO_MG, where ID_VEH_C be 1 and 2 for example. thanks

Comment: Finally your comment opn my eyes, I have to use OR instead AND. With AND has not sens. Thanks a lot :)